# WebDriver Grid with HtmlUnit on Node pegs the Node CPU

Tags: c#, webdriver, htmlunit, selenium-grid

I am usign C#, with Gallio/mbUnit to write a very simple set of tests that open a browser, navigate to google.com, type 'seleniumhq' in the search box, and click the search button.

I create my host with:

```
java -jar \"C:\\selenium-server-standalone-2.15.0.jar\" -role hub -port 4444
```

and my node with:

> java -jar \"C:\selenium-server-standalone-2.15.0.jar\"  -role node
>   -hub http://[hostIP]:4444/grid/register -port 5556 -browser browserName=htmlunit,platform=ANY,version=firefox,maxInstances=1

I create my webDriver instance, I use:

> driver = new RemoteWebDriver("http://localhost:4444/wd/hub",
>   DesiredCapabilities.HtmlUnitWithJavaScript());

I am monitoring my node machine and when the test commences, the CPU pegs to 99% with just 1 test running.  I get timeouts when waiting for the search button to display... it's there, just not visible, even after 40 seconds:

```
var wait = new WebDriverWait(WebDriver, new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 40)); 
wait.Until(m => m.FindElement(By.Name("btnG")).Displayed);
```

Any thoughts on why that element isn't visible for HtmlUnit consistently?

Any thoughts on why the CPU pegs at or near 100% and spikes in memory up to 800,000K for HtmlUnit on a remote node?

I have the copied the same test to create 10 identical tests and if I remove the click search button code, the HtmlUnit tests take 65 seconds.  This test is using two nodes, DegreeOfParallelism set at 10, and MaxInstances set at 5 for each node.  When I run the same tests with the same paramters with Chrome, they run in 35 seconds and I don't see the CPU going crazy.  Anybody have any ideas on this?  HtmlUnit is supposed to be about 4x's as fast from what I have read.  I am guessing that I have something wrong that should be fairly obvious.

Thanks for all help and suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

A bit late, but:

To find out what the HtmlUnitDriver is doing, get a thread dump using `jstack <pid>`. You'll probably see that it is deadlocked or stuck in a loop.

I've have had some deadlock & hanging issues using older HtmlUnit versions, but the latest [Selenium server versions](http://docs.seleniumhq.org/download/) (2.31.0) are using HtmlUnit 2.11 which seems to have resolved these issues.

It looks like you were using Selenium 2.15 which includes HtmlUnit 2.9, which could be the problem.